# how to select using multiple LIKE clauses that are constructed dynamically in MSSQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a Table Family like the following

```
Family_Name | Family_Members_Age
Johnson     | 45,60,56
Ken         | 78,67,40
David       | 40
```

Here is a proc I have

```
CREATE PROCEDURE getFamilyRowsByAge @Age nvarchar(30)
AS
SELECT * 
FROM Family
WHERE Family_members_age LIKE FILL_IN -- need to get this fill_in dynamically
```

The @Age param is supplied with comma separated String like `45,67`.
FILL_IN would be something like this for input String of "45,67" `LIKE '%45%' OR LIKE '%67%'`. I want this to be dynamically created by splitting input String for comma and joining with LIKE OR. Is there a way in MSSQL to do this?

```
Output:
Johnson     | 45,60,56
Ken         | 78,67,40
```

Here is another input and output:

```
input : 40, 67, 69
Output:
Johnson     | 45,60,56
Ken         | 78,67,40
David       | 40
```

Comment: Why don't you write `Split` function by yourself then `concat` each value by `Like %Value%`

Comment: Why don't just use the `IN` function in the `WHERE` clause instead of `LIKE` as it would give you precise answers to your input parameters.

Comment: `IN` will not work since it is not list. It is a String in DB as well as input to proc

Comment: `SELECT * FROM artists WHERE STRING_SPLIT(Family_members_age , ',') IN (@Age)` won't this help ?

Comment: so your solution will result in something like this after split is applied (which creates array of Strings) -> ['45','60','56'] IN `45,67` which is result in false, however, it should be true

Answer (score 1):

Based on those comments, try this:

```
USE tempdb;
GO

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS dbo.Family;
GO

CREATE TABLE dbo.Family
(
    FamilyID int IDENTITY(1,1) 
        CONSTRAINT PK_dbo_Family PRIMARY KEY,
    Family_Name varchar(100),
    Family_Members_Age varchar(max)
);
GO

INSERT dbo.Family (Family_Name, Family_Members_Age)
VALUES ('Johnson', '45,60,56'),
       ('Ken', '78,67,40'),
       ('David', '40');
GO

CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.GetFamilyRowsByAge 
@RequiredAges varchar(100)
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;
    SET XACT_ABORT ON;

    WITH FamilyAges
    AS
    (
        SELECT f.Family_Name, fma.Age
        FROM dbo.Family AS f
        CROSS APPLY (SELECT value AS Age FROM STRING_SPLIT(f.Family_Members_Age,',')) AS fma
    )
    SELECT fa.Family_Name, fa.Age 
    FROM FamilyAges AS fa
    WHERE fa.Age IN (SELECT value FROM STRING_SPLIT(@RequiredAges, ','));
END;
GO

EXEC dbo.GetFamilyRowsByAge '45,67,40';
GO
```

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve it by this simple way, Live demo [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=aa1b7b61c3bae58e4455e80f42da7c40)

**strSplit**

```
CREATE FUNCTION  [dbo].[strSplit] ( @string nvarchar( MAX), @splitter CHAR( 1) )  
RETURNS @res TABLE (id INT PRIMARY KEY, rank INT, val nvarchar( MAX) )  
AS  
BEGIN  
     IF SUBSTRING ( @string, len ( @string), 1)<>@splitter  
          SET @string= @string+@splitter  
     DECLARE @start INT, @word nvarchar(MAX), @charindex INT, @i INT  
     SET @i=1  
     SET @start=1  
     SET @charindex= CHARINDEX( @splitter, @string, @start)  
     WHILE (@charindex <> 0)BEGIN  
          SET @word= SUBSTRING( @string, @start, @charindex - @start)  
          SET @start= @charindex +1  
          SET @charindex= CHARINDEX( @splitter, @string, @start)  
          INSERT INTO @res  VALUES ( @start, @i, @word)  
          SET @i=@i+1  
     END  
     RETURN
END
```

**ContainString**

```
CREATE FUNCTION  [dbo].[ContainString] (@string1 nvarchar( MAX), @string2 nvarchar( MAX))  
RETURNS BIT
AS  
BEGIN  
     IF(EXISTS(SELECT TOP 1 a.val From strSplit(@string1, ',') a
               INNER JOIN strSplit(@string2, ',') b on a.val = b.val ))
     BEGIN
       RETURN 1
     END

     RETURN 0
END
```

**Select result**

```
SELECT * FROM Family WHERE [dbo].ContainString(Family_Members_Age, '45,67') = 1
SELECT * FROM Family WHERE [dbo].ContainString(Family_Members_Age, '40,67,69') = 1
```

Comment: will try out. Thanks

Comment: Does this answer your question? Let me know if you need any help @eagertoLearn

Answer (score 0):

The whole query within the proc will need to be dynamic. Then you can use something like STRING_SPLIT (2016 or later) to pull apart the comma-delimited value and build the string.
However, I'm unconvinced that's what you need. If you use LIKE, how are you going to avoid %9% matching a value like 91 ?

You might want to consider normalizing the table correctly instead. Why are there 3 ages within a single column? Why not just store it as 3 rows?

Comment: good point..this is a contrived example of production table. nothing much can be done on the schema itself. If not LIKE, what is better way to do it? how to split and build String as part of proc itself?

Comment: What you can do is to query the table, and to use a CROSS APPLY on the column with the multiple values. Within the CROSS APPLY logic, you use STRING_SPLIT to pull it apart.

Comment: If you can't change the table, you could get away with LIKE as long as you query it like this '%9,%' and make sure you append a comma to the column before you use the LIKE on it. That way, at least every value would have a trailing comma.

Comment: Sure. Give me a little while to make an example and I'll post it.

Answer (score 0):

Probably you need something like this .

```
SELECT 'Johnson'Family_Name,'45,60,56' Family_Members_Age 
into #YourTable
union all select 'Ken','78,67,40'
union all select 'David','40'

DECLARE  @WhereQuery varchar(250)='40, 67, 69', @Query nvarchar(250)

select @Query = 'select * from #YourTable' 

SET @WhereQuery = ' WHERE Family_Members_Age LIKE ''%'+ REPLACE (@WhereQuery,',','%'' OR Family_Members_Age LIKE ''%') + '%'''

SET @Query = @Query + @WhereQuery

EXEC SP_EXECUTESQL @Query
```